# Basic . ( Beginner in C)

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I wrote the following code in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("Enter a number %d",&num);
    printf("%d",num);
    
    return(0);
}
```

**This code after taking the input always returns a specific value around 32766, 32764, 32767, etc.**

Why is this happening and what are the specialities of these numbers??

Comment: `scanf("Enter a number %d",&num);` ==> `if (scanf("Enter a number %d",&num) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed.\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: That's not the right way to print a prompt for input. You should do `printf("Enter a number ");` and then just `scanf("%d", &num)`. And don't forget to check `scanf`s return value to see if everything went fine.

Comment: Note that `return` is a keyword, not a function name.  It is not wrong to put the value to be returned in parentheses, but neither is it required or (in most cases) idiomatic.

Comment: "_what are the specialities of these numbers?_" - Those numbers comes from reading the uninitialized variable `num`. It's uninitialized because the `scanf` fails.

Answer (score 5):

The string passed to `scanf` is not a prompt to be printed, but a format string to be matched by the user.  So as it's written it expects you to enter "Enter a number " followed by a number.

You should use `printf` to print the prompt, then have just the `%d` format specifier in the `scanf` format string.

```
printf("Enter a number ");
scanf("%d",&num);
```

And better yet, check the return value of `scanf` to ensure that the input matched the format specifier.

```
printf("Enter a number ");
if (scanf("%d",&num) == 1) {
    printf("%d",num);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you please tell me the specialty of these numbers that the output shows...

Comment: @Yogesh Because `num` wasn't initialized and no value was written to it, its value is *unspecified*, which basically means it contains whatever values happened to be sitting at that memory location when the variable was created.